# Count comma separated list in PHP with possibility to be 0

Tags: php, arrays, explode, substr

I want to count the number of items in a comma separated list.
To do this, I'm using `explode` and/or `substr_count`.

Like this:

```
explode(",", $array);
```

Or this:

```
substr_count( $array, ",") +1;
```

The problem is, that in a few cases, the comma separated list is empty.
In this case, both ways show me a result of 1.

How could I fix that to allow a result of 0?

Here is what I try to do. I want to show the number of items inside a cookie. And if it's empty, it should display 0 instead of 1.

```
<?php
    $compare_cookie         = $_COOKIE["wc_products_compare_products"];

    print_r($compare_cookie);

    if (empty($compare_cookie)) :
        $compare_cookie_array = 0;
    else :
        $compare_cookie_array   = explode(",", $compare_cookie);
    endif;

    $compare_cookie_result  = count($compare_cookie_array);

    // $result = substr_count( $_COOKIE["wc_products_compare_products"], ",") +1;

?>
<?php if ($compare_cookie_result >= 1) : ?>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger"><?php echo $compare_cookie_result; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT:** This works but it looks dirty...

```
if ( !empty($compare_cookie)):
    $compare_cookie_array   = explode(",", $compare_cookie);
    $compare_cookie_result  = count($compare_cookie_array);
else :
    $compare_cookie_result  = 0;
endif;
```

Comment: Empty, or has no commas present? `!empty()` could be done for actual empty. If you add 1 you always will have `1`. Why not just use the return from `substr_count`?

Comment: it's empty. But I tried `!empty()` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should show us more about what you are doing with this. Currently without some context its difficult to be of much help

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: `count($compare_cookie_array)` is the issue. See https://3v4l.org/h0UlN, I'm not sure why you don't just use the return of `substr_count` without adding one though.

Comment: OK, I see. But `echo $result = substr_count( $_COOKIE["wc_products_compare_products"], ",") +1;`is also 1. And if I don't add the `+1`. I get a 2 instead of a 3 for example

Comment: I added a working example.. but it looks not so nice and clean